# Adding a dir to the PATH for my account everywhere

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I want to append the directory `/home/bart/bin` to my `PATH`. By my `PATH`, I mean that it should be available whenever I login, whether it be via the terminal, Gnome, KDE or SSH, but not for other users. What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append your directory to PATH in /home/<user name>/.bashrc and source .bashrc from /home/<user name>/.profile using

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This way your changes will be available to you only in both GNOME & KDE and also in bash.

Do not edit /etc/profile as it will make the changes for all users.

Comment: Well, what do you know, apparently .profile already contains by default: `# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists \n
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then \n
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" \n
fi`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the appropriate line in .bashrc in your home folder should be enough for terminal and ssh. However, i don't understand how your path will make a difference in Gnome(maybe it might in the run utility, but not sure about it).

Add the line `PATH=/home/bart/bin:$PATH` in your .bashrc. Run `source ~/.bashrc` to test the new path settings if you change .bashrc from the terminal.

Comment: Indeed, that won't work for the run utility

Comment: Look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=969, it talks about changing /etc/profile, that may help you.

Comment: It works for me.  I just ran a script in the run dialog from ~/bin, which is only sourced in ~/.profile.  I just made a quick script to say some things with espeak and it did.  If you just created ~/bin you may need to log out.